# Touches on the center, image moves to the right while start zooming in a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, zooming

I am implementing a scrollview based on the code of Scrolling Madness found on git and I update it for an infinite image scrolling like a magazzine using three uiimageviews:
- 1st uiimageview: last page 
- 2nd uiimageview: first page 
- 3rd uiimageview: second page

The code uses the scrollRectToVisible to center in the screen the second uiimageview but when I start zooming it with the fingers on the center, the image moves to the right, leaving a part on screen and the left size on blank. The zoom works fine and everything but the behavior of the image isn't the correct.

I checked the Scrolling Madness project and I replicated the same behavior. The second image moves to the right, and the third one goes off screen.

Any ideas of how to correct this? I have tried to modify the contentoffset and other options of the scrollview but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another solution that worked for me after seeing another zoom project on the web. In the Scrolling Madness project, in the `setZoomingMode` function, set your scrollview's content size the same as your uiview that will be zoomed. Also, in my case, I modified the uiview's frame's origin to make it visible on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very useful method that solved the problem on this page: http://idevzilla.com/2010/10/04/uiscrollview-and-zoom/